# On Lockdown mode, why am I being prompted to allow an SD card to connect even though I don't enter any peripheral?

Tags: usb, bug, kernel, sd-card

I am running Venture 13.5 on a M1 MacBook Pro. Because Lockdown mode is on, I am prompted to approve/deny each time a USB device is plugged into my machine.

However, I am also randomly being prompted to approve/deny an SD card. During these occurrences, I do not enter any USB device, let alone an SD card. Why is this happening?

I've captures logs and timestamps I'll share below. I'm not exactly sure of what to look for and these logs don't tell me too much. Note that some data is redacted for privacy:

**At notification popup**

```
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.867963-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setActive(): [Port-SD Card@1: SD] active: YES (transportType: 12 [SD])
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.867985-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::_updateTRMState(): [Port-SD Card@1: SD] Updating TRM state...
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.867992-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::calculateAuthorizationState(): [Port-SD Card@1: SD] Calculating authorization state...
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.867999-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::calculateAuthorizationState_block_invoke(): [Port-SD Card@1: SD] *** RTRR ***
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.868029-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::handleStateChange(): [Port-SD Card@1: SD] Handling state change...
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.868038-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOServiceNotificationManager::sendMessages(): [Port-SD Card@1/SD] Sending 3 message(s)... (m_propertyChanged: YES)
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.868091-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) AppleNotificationQueue::processNotifications(): Processing 1 notification(s)...
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.868115-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOServiceNotificationManager::handleServiceReregistration(): [Port-SD Card@1/SD] Re-registering service...
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.868119-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::registerService(): [Port-SD Card@1: SD] Registering service SD@(null)... (transportType: 12, provider: Port-SD Card@1)
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.868283-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) AppleNotificationQueue::_handleNotifications(): Handling notifications...
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.868361-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPort::_updateConnectionActive_block_invoke(): [Port-SD Card@1] m_connectionActive: YES, m_connectionCount: 7, m_connectionUUID: AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.868397-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOServiceNotificationManager::sendMessages(): [Port-SD Card@1] Sending 2 message(s)... (m_propertyChanged: YES)
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.869605-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOServiceNotificationManager::sendMessages(): [Port-SD Card@1] Sending 3 message(s)... (m_propertyChanged: YES)
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.869607-0400 0xbb       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOgPTPPlugin)   IOTimeSyncTimeSyncTimePort(0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa): Other 0xaaaaaaaa
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.870997-0400 0xbb       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOgPTPPlugin)   IOTimeSyncTimeSyncTimePort(0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa): Other 0xaaaaaaaa
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.871095-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOServiceNotificationManager::handleServiceReregistration(): [Port-SD Card@1] Re-registering service...
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.871098-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPort::registerService(): [Port-SD Card@1] Registering service Port-SD Card@1...
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.871268-0400 0xbb       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOgPTPPlugin)   IOTimeSyncTimeSyncTimePort(0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa): Other 0xaaaaaaaa
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:15.871544-0400 0xbb       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOgPTPPlugin)   IOTimeSyncTimeSyncTimePort(0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa): Other 0xaaaaaaaa
```

**At notification close (triggered by me pressing "Don't allow")**

```
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:24.213640-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortUserClient::setUserAuthorizationStatus(): Setting user authorization status... (target: Port-SD Card@1, newUserAuthorizationStatus: 3 [Ignored])
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:24.213653-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPort::_setUserAuthorizationStatus(): [Port-SD Card@1] userAuthorizationStatus: 3 [Ignored]
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:24.213699-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOServiceNotificationManager::sendMessages(): [Port-SD Card@1] Sending 2 message(s)... (m_propertyChanged: YES)
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:24.213971-0400 0xbbbbbb   Default     0x0                  581    0    loginwindow: (LoginUIKit) messageType: kIOPort_Message_AuthorizationStateChange
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:24.213976-0400 0xbbbbbb   Default     0x0                  581    0    loginwindow: (LoginUIKit) Updating properties... (self.registryEntryID: 1111111111)
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:24.214538-0400 0xaaaaaa   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortUserClient::clientClose(): Stopping IOPortUserClient... (this: IOPortUserClient@(null), m_provider: Port-SD Card@1)
2023-0x-xx xx:xx:24.215275-0400 0xcc       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortUserClient::stop(): Stopping IOPortUserClient... (this: IOPortUserClient@(null), provider: Port-SD Card@1)
```

**Additional Information**

- This has been occurring since Lockdown mode has been on (Ventura 13.2)
- This happens randomly, sometimes once a week, sometimes twice a day

Comment: Are you using some kind of USB-C hub, dongle, or dock?    If so, what brand/model?

Comment: I have some Ankr dongles for USB/Ethernet ports. However, I get this alert both when the dongles are inserted and when they are not inserted. There does not appear to be any consistent pattern with what is plugged into the machine and when this appears (sometimes there is nothing plugged in, sometimes many ports are used by (what I would consider trusted) dongles).

Comment: I doubt you're seeing this while there's nothing attached; macOS can't detect something not attached.  I'll bet these Anker hubs/dongles have multiple connections (5-in-1 or 7-in-1) meaning you're not connecting one device, but up to 7.  An SD card reader needs to have firmware  to read and I'll bet that is what's getitng detected.

Comment: I have observed it multiple times with nothing attached, including today, which prompted this SE question :)

Comment: If you have nothing attached and it suddenly wants to to get permission to allow this phantom hardware to connect, you have a bug either in USB firmware or in macOS.  This isn't a "setting" you can change or modify as a user.  I'd open up a ticket with Apple Support.

Comment: Ok sounds good, thank you.